# How to detect the drag scrollbar event with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, overflow, scrollable

I have a scrollable `<div>` (`overflow: auto;`) and I want to detect the event of dragging the scroll bar inside the div. My current code is:

```
 var scrollableDiv =  $('.scrollablediv');   
 $(document).on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel touchmove scroll', scrollableDiv, function(e){   
    // do something  
 });
```

But it's only triggered when use the mouse wheel. If I drag the scrollbar of the `<div>` generated by the browser when the content overflows, the event is not triggered. **What should I add for it to work?**

Comment: What is `scrollableDiv`? selector, DOM element, jquery object?

Comment: AFAIK [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) doesn't expect jquery object as argument. Why not to bind listener immediately to `scrollableDiv`: `scrollableDiv.on(..)`?

Comment: Using [`on('scroll')` seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/cqpmL96o/) for me, and reacts to dragging the scroll-bar.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`$('.scrollablediv').scroll(function() {
    //do something
});`

```js
$("span").hide();

$(".scrollableDiv").scroll(function() {
   $("span").css( "display", "block" ).fadeOut("slow");
 });
```

```css
.scrollableDiv {
  height: 100px;
  width: 50px;
  overflow: auto;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scrollableDiv">
   foo<br>
  foo<br>
  foo<br>
  foo<br>
  foo<br>
  foo<br>
  foo<br>
  foo<br>
  foo<br>
  foo<br>
  foo<br>
  foo<br>
  foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>
</div>
<span>scrolling...</span>
```